# JSF2 h:outputLink encodes colon ':' as %3A

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, utf-8

I have URL as

```
/templates/includes/portal/Portal.xhtml?stparamdls=PRM0002:C:#{row.get("msm003_msa")}
```

which is getting interpreted as

```
/templates/includes/portal/prashanthPortal.xhtml?stparamdls=PRM0002%3AC%3ADevloper
```

can anyone tell me why the  colons are getting interpreted as '%3A' ?

The document encoding is `UTF-8`.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `:` is one of the [reserved characters in URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) and therefore needs to be escaped by percent encoding to prevent it from being interpreted differently by the webbrowser. JSF will automatically do that for you when the parameter is supplied as `<f:param>` in a `<h:outputLink>`. This behaviour is fully normal and expected.

If you're having technical problems with it, it's caused elsewhere and needs to be solved elsewhere than in the JSF `<h:outputLink>`.

Comment: Hi I tried putting the parameters in f:param tag but after doing that when I open that link in web inspector it shows up like this `templates/includes/portal/Portal.xhtml?stparamdls=PRM0002%3AC%3ADevloper` where as it should actually be encoded as `templates/includes/portal/Portal.xhtml?stparamdls=PRM0002:C:Devloper` can you tell me what else can be done for this?

Comment: The same answer still applies. This behavior is fully expected and shouldn't cause any problems. It helps perhaps if you elaborate in detail what problems exactly you're having with it.

Comment: `<h:outputLink value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/templates/includes/portal/prashanthPortal.xhtml" target="_self">
<f:param name="stparamdls" value="PRM0002:C:#{subItem.get('msm003_msa012')}"/>`  i have added the parameters in the format mentioned above,still when i click on the h:commandLink it is like this `http://localhost:8080/eWeb/templates/includes/portal/prashanthPortal.xhtml?stparamdls=PRM0002%3AC%3ADevloper` is there anything else that i am doing wrong?